# Using realm for complex objects android

Tags: android, object, realm

I started using realm. it seemed to work fine, but I have some questions. When I use realm for simple object with primitive fields, everything is ok. But I'm facing issues using it for complex objects.

For example I have a class `Passenger`. It has several fields

```
Segment segment;
Documents documents;
....
```

Each field also has sub objects. Segment class

```
Flight flight;
Arrival arrival;
int pnrRequest;
```

So as I understand I will have several tables and I need one-to-many relations to connect this tables. What i want is to store passenger list inside database.

The problem is that I already have this classes as a model, but they dont extend RealmObject. I don't want to have duplicate classes one for model and one for database. Is there a way to avoid duplication of files and conversion from one model to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface) it's posible:

> An alternative to extending the RealmObject base class is implementing the RealmModel interface and adding the @RealmClass annotation.

Comment: If i will create instances of this objects will it create also automatically a record inside realm?

Comment: Of cource. Use your models as typical RealmObjects

Comment: у меня довольно большой объект и есть список этих объектов(пассажиров), а что если сериализовать данные, залить в базу, а потом десериализовать когда мне нужно. Насколько это медленно будет происходить? дело в том что мне нужно хранить список пассажиров в контексте текущей сессии и потом этот список можно убить. Пока я его храню в статическом классе что не есть хорошо, но работает оно быстро.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему плохо хранить сессию в памяти... Кажется, что как раз таки в базу данных её толкать не стоит

Comment: согласен. Я тоже хочу хранить в раме, но у меня есть директор, который любит копаться в чужом коде, он против хранения в раме. хз. буду делать как я считаю нужным. А реалм буду только юзать если что-то нужно оффлайн хранить

Comment: Евгений, уверен, что у Вас, как у технического специалист,а найдётся достаточно аргументов в пользу InMemory решения

Answer (score 1):

Realm requires that all models that should be persisted must extend `RealmObject` or implement the interface `RealmModel` (see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface). If neither of these approaches work for you, you will need to duplicate the class and have conversion methods between them.

Comment: Hello, can you help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060003/speed-of-search-operation-in-a-realm-database