# Speed of search operation in a Realm database

Tags: java, android, performance, search, realm

This is the model for my `RealmObject` class :

```
    public class ARDatabase extends RealmObject
    {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String uid;

    private String namex;
    private String desc;
    private boolean isVideo;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private String urlImg;
    private String urlApp;
    private int updates;
    private boolean isDownloaded;
    private String location;

    public ARDatabase(){}

    public String getUid()
    {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getNamex()
    {
        return namex;
    }

    public void setNamex(String namex)
    {
        this.namex = namex;
    }

    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc)
    {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public boolean getIsVideo()
    {
        return isVideo;
    }

    public void setIsVideo(boolean isVideo)
    {
        this.isVideo = isVideo;
    }

    public boolean getIsDeleted()
    {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted)
    {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public String getUrlImg()
    {
        return urlImg;
    }

    public void setUrlImg(String urlImg)
    {
        this.urlImg = urlImg;
    }

    public String getUrlApp()
    {
        return urlApp;
    }

    public void setUrlApp(String urlApp)
    {
        this.urlApp = urlApp;
    }

    public int getUpdates()
    {
        return updates;
    }

    public void setUpdates(int updates)
    {
        this.updates = updates;
    }

    public boolean getIsDownloaded()
    {
        return isDownloaded;
    }

    public void setIsDownloaded(boolean isDownloaded)
    {
        this.isDownloaded = isDownloaded;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

And this is how I search for the `uid` from my default realm:

```
final ARDatabase db = mRealm.where(ARDatabase.class).equalTo("uid",imageTitles.get(result)).findFirst();
```

Now, the **question** is: Considering I have 10-100 objects inside my realm, how fast would the search be?

The use case is for an image recognition app. When the app recognizes an image it returns the `uid`, and based on the `uid` I need to provide an overlay on the screen with the information associated with the `uid` ASAP.

Now since I have around 10-100 objects, would a linear search `O(n)` or a generic binary search `O(log n)` would be faster than the `Realm` search I've used above? Or is it possible to tweak `Realm` to get faster results? (in case it's not performing the fastest way now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the search in Realm will always be faster since you can execute the entire search inside the C++ core. Doing the search yourself will mean you occur the overhead of going back and forth between Java and C++.

The only requirement for doing fast searching for single elements is that you have an `@Index` annotation on the field, but in your case you already have `@PrimaryKey` which automatically applies the `@Index` annotation as well.

So your query is as fast as it can be. Besides, for 10-100 objects, no matter what you do, it will probably appear instantaneous to the user.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it perfectly :)

Comment: Additionally to your point, it might be worth using findFirstAsync and using a change listener, if the query is being run from the UI thread that is.